# GNOME 14.04: Explode windows, wrong screen?

Tags: gnome, 14.04

Normally in GNOME when you hit the super key the windows explode so you can select between them, and the windows appear on the monitor that they're opened on.

I have 4 monitors, and since upgrading to 14.04 the Windows on my far right monitor always appear on my centre screen when I hit the super key.

For example, with the windows open normally:

[image: normal]

Yet when I hit the super key:

[image: super key]

See how window 3 has moved to the middle monitor, but window 1 and 2 have stayed in the same place (like they should)?

Is this a known issue, or something to do with my configuration?

I'm using the open source AMD drivers if that's significant.

Comment: For the record I resolved this issue by switching to proprietary drivers.